# Generate unique base64 in database

Tags: postgresql, base64, uuid, playframework-2.2

I have a play framework 2.2  **java** project with **PGSql** database.

I want to **uniquely** **identify** some objects in DB with the shortest **base64** string.

I need to **generate them and ensure it does not exist** in DB.

Is there any play or ebean mecanism to do that ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it have to be Base64? whats wrong with a vanilla incrementing integer identity value (which can be expresses a a short b64 string anyway)

Comment: A integer will not be "length optimized". And it must go well in an url. I was wondering if you have a base64 incremeting algorithm.

Comment: This is usually done (URL Shortening services etc) using an integer and Base **36** encoded string which will give a short result string comprising A-Z0-9

Comment: Thanks, any code sample ?

Comment: http://www.jamiebegin.com/base36-conversion-in-postgresql/ Its a common task, I don't know about "PlayFramework" which is probably a better place to do the conversion

Comment: There is a pure SQL version (for converting integers to custom bases - up to 36) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24425022/convert-value-from-string-representation-in-base-n-to-numeric/24425965#24425965

Comment: I need to do it in java

Answer (score 0):

Check the `uuid` type

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-uuid.html

and the `uuid_generate_v4()` function from the `uuid-ossp` module

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/uuid-ossp.html

```
select uuid_generate_v4();
           uuid_generate_v4           
--------------------------------------
 df30e78c-dfcd-4df4-8a9f-928329635382
```