# Creating a character sequence on postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

So, I have this sequence referenced on a table column where everytime I do an insert its value is defined by `nextval('ptable_pr_codigo_seq'::regclass)`

```
CREATE SEQUENCE public.ptable_pr_codigo_seq
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 103
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE public.ptable_pr_codigo_seq
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Now, how can I make a new sequence so everytime i do an insert the value is not a number but a character in a [A~ZZZ] range?.

```
Example: First insert column value = A
         Second                    = B
         Third                     = C
         27th                      = AA
         ...
         ?Th                       = ZZZ
```

Comment: Use a normal sequence, then convert the integer value to a "base 26" string, see e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24425965/330315

Answer (score 0):

Challenge accepted ;)

I do not think there is any way to do that with only PostgreSQL sequence mechanism ([1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html))
But If you really need something like that (and I am quite interested on why you need something like this), you can do a function that return you the next value that you want and put it into a trigger.

For example, create a table first :

```
create table test (test_id varchar);
```

Use a function like this one below

```
create or replace function next_id_test()
 returns trigger language plpgsql as $function$
begin
    with cte_conform_char_list as
    (
        select val, row_number() over (order by val), lead(val) over (order by val)
        from (values ('A'), ('B'), ('C'), ('D'), ('E'), ('F')) as t(val) -- you can continue this list as much as you want it ;)
        order by 1
    )
    , cte_built_char_list as
    (
        select 
            cte.val
            , cte.row_number
            , coalesce(cte.lead, cte_2.val) as next_char
        from cte_conform_char_list cte
            left outer join cte_conform_char_list cte_2
                on cte_2.row_number = cte.row_number - (select max(row_number) from cte_conform_char_list) +1
    )
    select 
        case 
            when row_number < (select max(row_number) from cte_built_char_list)
                then repeat(next_char, cast(rank() over (partition by row_number order by test_id) as int)) 
                else repeat(next_char, cast(rank() over (partition by row_number order by test_id) + 1 as int))
        end as next_test_id into new.test_id
    from test T
        inner join cte_built_char_list cte on substring(T.test_id from 1 for 1) = cte.val
    order by char_length(test_id), test_id;

    return new;
end;
$function$;
```

Attach the function to a before trigger

```
create trigger tg_test before insert on test for each row execute procedure next_id_test();
```

Insert a value that doesn't really matter (it will be changed anyway)

```
insert into test values ('ttt');
```

Then you can observe you have the right character.

```
select *
from test;
```

I know that's a little heavy way but I do not see any other one. 
The function is probably not perfect but I do not have a lot of time :)

Hope it's going to help you ;)