# SQL query to append string to duplicate column value in a table and return the result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have search but couldn't find existing answer. I have a data like below up to 2 million plus rows.

data =

```
id,     name,     latitude,      longitude
S226,   Farm 1,   -87.511372,     176.831784
S011,   Farm 1,    -3.978185,     -173.035526
S540,   Farm 10,   20.242715,     -119.461222
S795,   Farm 10,   -49.680679,    107.766038
```

The name field has duplicate value as in above say up to 1 million rows are duplicated.

When I run the code

```
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name) As no
FROM data;
```

I got

```
id,     name,     latitude,      longitude      no
S226,   Farm 1,   -87.511372,    176.831784     1
S011,   Farm 1,    -3.978185,    -173.035526    2
S540,   Farm 10,   20.242715,    -119.461222    1
S795,   Farm 10,   -49.680679,   107.766038     2
```

What sql query can I write to return the four columns minus the no column and
i. append _A to name where no is 1
ii. append _B to name where no is 2
iii. append _C to name for else value

So the result will look like

```
id,     name,        latitude,     longitude  
S226,   Farm 1_A,   -87.511372,    176.831784 
S011,   Farm 1_B,    -3.978185,    -173.035526
S540,   Farm 10_A,   20.242715,    -119.461222
S795,   Farm 10_B,   -49.680679,   107.766038
```

Comment: So what you need to know is how to convert number 1 to character A, etc. https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-string-functions/postgresql-chr/

Comment: @jarlh not really may be a case kind of query that append the string based on the no. like `case 1, name = 'Farm 1' +' _A'`

Comment: try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55816664/creating-a-character-sequence-on-postgresql

Comment: @nbk I tried  it and use an insert statement like with over 2million rows
`
INSERT INTO data (id, name, latitude, longitude)
SELECT DISTINCT id, locationname, latitude, longitude
FROM stage_data;`
It has been loading for more than 8 minutes now.
I feel like it is running an infinite query

Comment: make a new column add the new text and update only columns that are not NULL, so the load is made only once

Comment: Can you have more than 26 of the same duplicate?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I have up to a million record of the duplicate out of two million.

Comment: @Wacademy but how many duplicates do you have of a single item?

Comment: @Joel mostly two duplicates

Comment: Okay. If it were me, I'd want to either be sure I didn't have a pathologic record with duplicates that would take me beyond Z or that I knew how may code would behave if I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a simple `case` statement to add the suffix.

```
with tab as (
SELECT id, name, latitude, longitude, 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) As no
FROM data
)
select 
  id, name || 
  case when no = 1 then '_A' 
  when no = 2 then '_B' else '_C' 
  end as name, 
  latitude, longitude
from tab

id  |name     |latitude  |longitude  |
----+---------+----------+-----------+
S011|Farm 1_A | -3.978185|-173.035526|
S226|Farm 1_B |-87.511372| 176.831784|
S540|Farm 10_A| 20.242715|-119.461222|
S795|Farm 10_B|-49.680679| 107.766038|
```

Additional note on *ordering* in `row_number`

Using the *same* column for partition and order is not meaningfull (`PARTITION BY name ORDER BY name`) and will produce a *non-deterministic* result (different result on repeated executions). Use some other column of the table (idealy the combination of the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` columns should be *unique*).